# how to remove Python distutils shared library (dynamic module)

Tags: python, pip, shared-libraries, distutils

I accidentally compiled and installed a shared lib using `disutil`'s `setup` and `Extention`, that was named `py` which shadowed the default module `py`.

Trying, results

```
$ pip uninstall py
Found existing installation: py 0.0.0
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'py'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Is there anyway to remove such package?

Comment: Go to your python location directory in `site-packages` folder you can remove this package

Comment: > we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

that's the problem, since it is a `distutils` package, we don't really know which file is responsible for this package.

thus doing `find .local/lib/python3.8/site-packages -name py` or `ls .local/lib/python3.8/site-packages  | grep py 
`

brings up nothing.